# Apache Beam - monitoring a pipeline and querying status of a stage

Tags: apache-beam

While executing an Apache Beam pipeline, I would like to update the status of the pipeline in a database.

I want to do this so that I can do a review at the end of the day and see how many pipeline executions got fully completed, what's the current stage at which most pipelines are executing currently, etc.

What is the best way to get this information from Apache Beam's Java or Python API?